# Load tests and content files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

Can visual studio load test request css, javascripts, images and other files when it run web performance tests?

Comment: What would it mean for an image to "fail" a test?

Comment: Requests per second < some threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, visual studio requests these static files internally as dependent requests for the main request like .aspx, .html and so on. In the web test there is property called as "ParseDepedentRequest" which should be set to True. This property is responsible for calling all dependent requests.

Answer (score 1):

Those sub page requests are generated and tested during a normal page read. I.e. if you record a visual studio test for a page, the items it requires to load will also be recorded and the test will fail if any of those items does not exist.

Visual Studio simulates caching for these files however, so if you want to load test a "worst case" scenario, you will want to set the "Percentage of new users" property to 100%.